# Is copy() a good practice in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I working with DataFrames a lot and sometimes I need to replace values of whole column to another.
Usually I got a `SettingWithCopyWarning`. So if I got it i just copy my df and work is progressing.

Example:

```
df
name male
sd   Female
as   Male
we   Female
dd   Female

df = df.copy()
df['male'] = df['male'].replace({'Female':'F', 'Male':'M'})
```

result:

```
df
name male
sd   F
as   M
we   F
dd   F
```

So I copied my frame and changing values on copy. If I understand good I copy a frame. So I using 2x memory? And even If I omit `df = df.copy()` my code work fine but I got error info. Output still is ok.

So... I didn't found clear enough explanation, so I'm asking here. Is a good practice to copy my frames? Maybe is a different, better way?

Comment: `df = df.copy()` is ... useless. It won't use 2x memory because you're assigning a copy to the same variable but it might use time for nothing (and may consume temporarily a few more memory).

Comment: @CorentinLimier Thanks for memory explanation. Ok, so it's just an info : "dude, u changing ur dataframe. Maybe create copy" ? And that's all?

Comment: It's the opposite. Quoting from the link above : `SettingWithCopyWarning is to show users (and especially new users) that they may be operating on a copy and not the original as they think`

Comment: @CorentinLimier Ok, thank u for explanation. So resume: it's not a good practice and I can turn off that warning monit in Ide options without concerns.